# outline of border in css

Tags: html, css

I'm new with css, but the thing that i'm trying to do is slightly complicated, at least for me. I have a picture that i want to cover with a circle, transparent from the inside, black from the outside.
this is what I've accomplished so far:

```css
.roundedBorder {
    border: 1px solid #1EC865;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-radius: 81px;
}
.img { position:absolute; top:6px; left:6px; width:81px;
}
```

```html
<img class=img src="http://suptg.thisisnotatrueending.com/archive/13559636/images/1295334728830.jpg">
<div style="position:absolute;width:70px;height:70px;border-width: 4px;position:absolute;" class="roundedBorder">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dmL56kek/

now i'm looking to cover the outer of circle with a solid color.

PS: i don't want to apply any style on the image because it won't work in my case.

Comment: Why not just give your image a `border-radius: 100%`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/CRafT/dmL56kek/1/

Comment: as i say it's complicated, i'm using a cropper and trying to preview the cropped area using the pluguin, the preview image, which is the image i'm trying not to act on is actually generated by the plugin like this <div style="overflow: hidden; float: right; width: 81px; height: 81px;" id="prevDiv"><img src="xxxxxxx" style="display: block; width: 304.608px; height: 171.342px; min-width: 0px !important; min-height: 0px !important; max-width: none !important; max-height: none !important; margin-left: -13.0752px; margin-top: -6.78131px;"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little change is css would help and i have used `width:78px` with a calculation that width of outer div is 70px and border is 4px from left and right.

```css
.roundedBorder {
    border: 1px solid #1EC865;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-radius: 81px;
}
.img { position:absolute; top:8px; left:8px; width:78px; border-radius:100%;}
```

```html
<img class=img src="http://suptg.thisisnotatrueending.com/archive/13559636/images/1295334728830.jpg">
<div style="position:absolute;width:70px;height:70px;border-width: 4px;position:absolute;" class="roundedBorder">
</div>
```